# iPhone 6 MapView crash

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I added a `MKMapView` to my app. as soon as I added it it started to crash. But its running well and I can see the Map is loading in iPhone 4s semulator. What could be the reason for this?  I get `Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue` this in the debug console.

What would be the reason for this? Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: The reason is there "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue"
Can you post your related code

Comment: I didnt add any code. I added Mapview from xib tot he storyboard. And set the IBOutlet. Also imported the library. and set the delegate,, when I decrerease the mapview size it doesnt crash,, but I cant add it larger,, I want to add it fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

MKMapView uses more memory. so in devices with small RAM app will crash.

you can release some memory used by MKMapview in viewWillDisappear:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
   mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
   mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
   mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
   mapView.delegate = nil;
   mapView = nil;
   [mapView removeFromSuperview];

}
```

You can try this to release some memory that will help to prevent your app from crash:

1. Avoid stacking autoreleased objects
   When you **instantiate objects like NSString with no explicit allocation they live until the release of your autorelease pool** – typically until your app quits. Extensive usage of such techniques may lead to a lot of garbage in RAM. Use
   **NSString initWithContentsOfFile:**
   so you can later release it instead of
   NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:
   . The same rule applies to
   **UIImage imageNamed:**
   – this is not recommended to use for image loading.
2. Handle memory warnings
   Unload unnecessary resources when handling memory warning. Even if you can’t unload any of your stuff call
   **[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]** in all your UIViewControllers. That will by default free some resources like UI controls on non-front views. Failing to handle this event may make iOS decide that your app deserves killing.
3. Consider **limited usage of animated view transitions Animations like flip transition** are noticed to cause RAM usage spikes when executed. This feature is very neat and should be used in many cases but it may trigger memory warnings in a heavily loaded multitasking environment. In particular we strongly recommend to avoid animating OpenGL views.

Hope this helps.